# How can i combine all the contents of a List to one value Python

Tags: python, string

If I were to get the input of someone and put it into a list. How would I combine this into one big string.

```
user_input = input()
listed = list(user_input)
```

I am having trouble with this since the contents are unknown. Is there anyway to make it one big string again(combining all the contents of the list). Is there anything I can import into my code to do this for me

Comment: why are you converting the input to list in the first place?why do you want to convert it to string again?

Comment: I want to take something out in a project i am programming like taking out the letter "t" if it is in the string and then putting the string back together again with the changes

Comment: you need to add to your description

Answer (score 1):

To join a list together, you can use the `join` method. Simply use it as a method on whatever string you want to have placed between each entry in the list:

```
>>> ls = ['Hello,','world!']
>>> ' '.join(ls)
'Hello, world!'
```